# Walk through a table to grab unique certificate numbers for shares

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, laravel, eloquent

The table I am working with is named shares. Assuming `$share` is an instance of the model `Share`. A `share` belongs to a `company`.

```
| id | company_id | number_of_shares |
| 31 | 1          | 3                |
| 33 | 1          | 9                |
| 34 | 1          | 4                |
```

I want to call `$share->getCertificate()` and have it return a certificate number, these should be:

```
id 31 -> 1
id 33 -> 2
id 34 -> 3
```

**Note:** this increments a unique certificate number based on its location in the table.

Then when I call `$share->getDistinctive()` I wish to have it return the following:

```
id 31 -> array('start' => 1, 'end' => 3)
id 33 -> array('start' => 4, 'end' => 13)
id 34 -> array('start' => 14, 'end' => 18)
```

**Note:** this increments based on the number of shares starting at 1

**Assumptions**

Table will always be ordered by id

I am using laravel 4.0.

Happy for someone to recommend a better title so that other people can find the the solution to their problem.

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out - not sure why I thought it would've been more complicated.

`getCertificateNumber()`

```
public function getCertificateNumber()
{
    $x=1;

    foreach($this->company->holdings()->get() as $holding)
    {
        if($holding->id == $this->id)
        {
            return $x;
        }

        $x++;
    }
}
```

`getDistinctiveNumbers()`

```
public function getDistinctiveNumbers()
{
    $shares=0;

    foreach($this->company->holdings()->orderBy('id')->get() as $holding)
    {
        if($holding->id == $this->id)
        {
            return ['start'=> $shares + 1, 'end' => $shares + $this->number_shares];
        }

        $shares += $holding->number_shares;
    }
}
```